# DIVI Gallery Module: Clicking image takes user to custom URL, instead of lightbox

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gallery, divi

I am trying to build a gallery (using the DIVI gallery module) where the user can click a picture and it takes them to a custom URL (instead of opening in a lighbox).

I've already used ACF to add a custom URL field to my images. But I cannot figure out how to disable the lightbox and replace it with the custom URL I've assigned. Is there any way to do this with code?